# Oracle PL/SQL Pass row type as constructor parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is it possible to pass table%rowtype as parameter in a constructor ?

I have something like this and this works

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE shape AS OBJECT (
    name VARCHAR2(30),
    area NUMBER,
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION shape(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY shape, name VARCHAR2)
                               RETURN SELF AS RESULT,
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION shape(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY shape, name VARCHAR2, 
                               area NUMBER) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
) NOT FINAL;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY shape AS
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION shape(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY shape, name VARCHAR2) 
                               RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
    BEGIN
        SELF.name := name;
        SELF.area := 0;
        RETURN;
    END;
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION shape(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY shape, name VARCHAR2, 
                                area NUMBER) RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
    BEGIN
        SELF.name := name;
        SELF.area := area;
        RETURN;
    END;
END;
/
```

However i need to pass a table%row as parameter as well

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE shape AS OBJECT (
    name VARCHAR2(30),
    area NUMBER,
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION shape(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY shape, name VARCHAR2)
                               RETURN SELF AS RESULT,
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION shape(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY shape, name VARCHAR2, 
                               area NUMBER) RETURN SELF AS RESULT,
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION shape(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY shape, ctrl CONTROL%ROWTYPE) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
) NOT FINAL;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY shape AS
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION shape(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY shape, name VARCHAR2) 
                               RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
    BEGIN
        SELF.name := name;
        SELF.area := 0;
        RETURN;
    END;
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION shape(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY shape, name VARCHAR2, 
                                area NUMBER) RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
    BEGIN
        SELF.name := name;
        SELF.area := area;
        RETURN;
    END;
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION shape(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY shape, ctrl CONTROL%ROWTYPE) RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
    BEGIN
        SELF.area := NULL;
        RETURN;
    END;
END;
/
```

LINE/COL  ERROR

---

0/0       PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
8/63      PLS-00329: schema-level type has illegal reference to SCHEMA_A.CONTROL
Errors: check compiler log

Type Body SHAPE compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR

---

0/0       PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
1/11      PLS-00905: object SCHEMA_A.SHAPE is invalid
1/11      PLS-00304: cannot compile body of 'SHAPE' without its specification
Errors: check compiler log

Is something like this possible ?

Comment: Apparently not. I suggest passing in the primary key of the row in question and then fetching the desired row within the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to take a slightly different method, you can create an [object table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6):

```sql
CREATE TYPE control_type AS OBJECT (
  id NUMBER(8,0),
  name VARCHAR2(30),
  area NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE control OF control_type(
  CONSTRAINT control__id__pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO control (id, name, area)
SELECT 1, 'square', 42 FROM DUAL;
```

Then instead of expecting a `%ROWTYPE` in the cursor, you could pass the underlying object type for that table:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE shape AS OBJECT (
    name VARCHAR2(30),
    area NUMBER,
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION shape(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY shape, name VARCHAR2)
                               RETURN SELF AS RESULT,
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION shape(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY shape, name VARCHAR2, 
                               area NUMBER) RETURN SELF AS RESULT,
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION shape(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY shape, ctrl control_type) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
) NOT FINAL;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY shape AS
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION shape(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY shape, name VARCHAR2) 
                               RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
    BEGIN
        SELF.name := name;
        SELF.area := 0;
        RETURN;
    END;
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION shape(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY shape, name VARCHAR2, 
                                area NUMBER) RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
    BEGIN
        SELF.name := name;
        SELF.area := area;
        RETURN;
    END;
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION shape(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY shape, ctrl control_type) RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
    BEGIN
        SELF.name := ctrl.name;
        SELF.area := ctrl.area;
        RETURN;
    END;
END;
/
```

Then you can use `VALUE(column_alias)` in a `SELECT` from an object table to pass the table's underlying object type into your constructor:

```sql
SELECT s.shape.area,
       s.shape.name
FROM   (
  SELECT SHAPE(VALUE(c)) AS shape
  FROM   control c
) s;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> SHAPE.AREA | SHAPE.NAME
> ---------: | :---------
>         42 | square
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9788c1cb2477f1a0789cc56d2ea2382b)*

Answer (score 0):

if this record type is only to assign a subset of fields 1:1 you can do this

1. define constructor method

```
CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION shape(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY shape, ctrl shape) RETURN SELF AS RESULT,
```

2. or simply define another object with fields you need and use it insted of %rowtype in your constructor

```
CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION shape(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY shape, ctrl t_control_rec) RETURN SELF AS RESULT,
```

here's the record type definition

```
CREATE TYPE t_control_rec AS OBJECT (
  id NUMBER
  name VARCHAR2(30),
  area NUMBER
);
/
```

here's a demo for 1st approach:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
    l_base_shape    shape := shape('square', 42);
    l_ctrl_shape    shape; --l_control_rec   t_control_rec; 
BEGIN
    l_base_shape.display();
    WITH imaginary_table AS (
        SELECT 1 id, 'tesseract' name, 2048 area
        FROM dual
    )
    SELECT shape(it.name, it.area) --t_control_rec(it.name, it.area)
    INTO l_ctrl_shape
    FROM imaginary_table it;

    l_ctrl_shape.display();                     
    l_base_shape := shape(l_ctrl_shape);
    l_base_shape.display();
END;
/
```

added additional method shape.display()

```
    member procedure display is
    begin
      dbms_output.put_line(self.name|| ':'|| self.area);  
    end;
```

*it's very similar to @MT0 approach, but without table with object based records